# $α : [a_1,a_2,...] → [\lim_{i→∞} {a_i}− a_1,\lim_{i→∞}{a_i}−a_2,...]$. Find all eigenvalues of $α$, eigenspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, limits, convergence-divergence, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $W$ be the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^∞$ consisting of all convergent sequences and let $α$
be the endomorphism of $W$ defined by
$α : [a_1,a_2,...] →  [\lim_{i→∞} {a_i}− a_1,\lim_{i→∞}{a_i}−a_2,...]$.
Find all eigenvalues of $α$ and, for each eigenvalue, find the corresponding
eigenspace.

I'm lost as to how to find the eigenvalues of this mapping. Any solutions/help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We can first consider the subspace $C_0 \subset W$ consisting of all sequences converging to $0$.
For a sequence $a = (a_1, a_2 , \dots) \in C_0$ we have $$\alpha (a) = ( 0 - a_1, 0-a_2 , \dots ) = (-a_1, - a_2, \dots ) = -(a_1, a_2, \dots ) = -a$$
So we have $C_0$ is (part) of the eigenspace of eigenvalue $-1$.

Now, you know that $W = C_0 + V$, where $V$ consist of all constant sequences.
Then for $\gamma \in V$, we have $$\alpha (\gamma) = (\gamma - \gamma , \gamma -\gamma, \dots) = (0,0, \dots ) = 0 \gamma$$
So we have that $V$ is (part) of the eigenspace of eigenvalue $0$.

Now, you can also show that $C_0$ and $V$ are the eigenspaces, which is left as a exercise for the reader.